# Giving a YAML file more than one key, while only using one value for the keys

Tags: ruby, key, yaml

I have an issue where I need to make a yaml file that will contain the following keys:

> ETA SOL VETS EMC

From these keys I need one value that will be an email address all four of the keys are the same email address, is it possible to make a yaml file with more then one key, and only one value..?

For example:

```
agencies:
         - ETA
         - SOL
         - VETS
         - EMC
            advocate_email: "example@example.com" #<= Give these four the same value
         - some
         - other
         - ones
             advocate_email: "example1@example1.com" #<= Give three another value.. So one and so forth
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** UPDATE **
I think you have multiple emails and each group has a longer list.

```
group1:
  email: me@email.com
  list:
    - ETA
    - SOL
    - VETS
group2:
  email: me2@email.com
  list:
    - ONE
    - TWO
    - THREE
```

** END UPDATE **

If I understand correctly and that you want the same email:

```
email: &email me@email.com

emails:
  ETA: *email
  SOL: *email
  VETS: *email
```

Output:

```
pry(main)> YAML.load(File.read('foo.yml'))
=> {"email"=>"me@email.com", "emails"=>{"ETA"=>"me@email.com", "SOL"=>"me@email.com", "VETS"=>"me@email.com"}}
```

Comment: If you have multiple emails, you can also create groups, each group would have an email, and a list of emails.

Comment: So I would have to create another aspect for each email correct? And then for each group I can call it using something like: `*email`

Comment: I see how that could work, but I'd have to be able to call the advocates from a single key for example: `['group'][etc]['email']` so giving them `group1`,`group2`,etc. won't work in this case..

Comment: Add all groups under a groups key and loop through the groups array. YAML can act just like a db. It depends what you want to do.

Comment: Your yaml doesn't validate.

Comment: @7stud There was  a typo that was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the best solution to your problem, but you can use anything as a key in a YAML mapping, including a sequence (array). It looks like this:

```yaml
agencies:
  ? - ETA
    - SOL
    - VETS
    - EMC
  : advocate_email: example@example.com
  ? - some
    - other
    - ones
  : advocate_email: example1@example1.com
```

Each `?` denotes a key and the subsequent `:` denotes a value. To demonstrate:

```
require "pp"
require "yaml"

yaml = <<YML
agencies:
  ? - ETA
    - SOL
    - VETS
    - EMC
  : advocate_email: example@example.com
  ? - some
    - other
    - ones
  : advocate_email: example1@example1.com
YML

pp YAML.load(yaml)
# => {"agencies"=>
#      {["ETA", "SOL", "VETS", "EMC"]=>{"advocate_email"=>"example@example.com"},
#       ["some", "other", "ones"]=>{"advocate_email"=>"example1@example1.com"}}}
```

Comment: Interesting "new" syntax! :-)

Comment: Say  I want to look up the email for ETA.  How would I do that?  Is that practical?

Comment: It's not as practical as it would be with @Abdo's answer. It would look like this: `data["agencies"].find {|keys, val| keys.include?("ETA") }.last` (whereas with Abdo's it would be `data["emails"]["ETA"]`).

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't know you could use `?` as syntax

Comment: +1 I did not know you could do this in Ruby. Although the YAML spec allows arbitrary nodes as mapping keys (as long as they are unique), my `ruamel.yaml` parser for Python only allows scalars and sequences (as the `dict` keys have to be hashable). I have to think about a solution for that. Minor detail: the double quotes around the email addresses are superfluous

Comment: @Anthon Quite right about the quotes. They're leftover from copying OP's code. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get correctly but I think you want something like

```
emails:
  ETA: email1@example.com
  SOL: email2@example.com
  VETS: email3@example.com
```

Comment: Yes, but it would be easier if I could put all of them to have one value, the emails for those three are the same email.